# The header of response web service in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, response, hashcode

The format of response

```
adbc91a43e988a3b5b745b8529a90b61
<RESPONSE Stamp="YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ" RE="…" ERR_TEXT="…">
 <PaymentID>3242343</PaymentID>
</RESPONSE>
```

The first line of the response consists of a md5-hash xml-response + parameters hash, followed by
xml-response.
The main element of xml-response is called RESPONSE...

How and where to add the hash code?
Thanks

I have XML without hashcode. My code in c#

```
[WebMethod]
public RESPONSE GET( string id)
{
    RESPONSE res = new RESPONSE();
    res.ERR_TEXT = "";
    res.RE = "";            
    res.Stamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddthh-mm-ssz");
    res.PaymentID = id;
    return res;            
}

public class RESPONSE
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ERR_TEXT { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string RE { get; set; }        
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Stamp { get; set; }

    public string PaymentID { get; set; } 
}
```

In output get only XML. But must still pass the hash code.

I must send a response to a client request. And they want that at response body was hash and xml. And how it should look like I can not understand.

Comment: Your question is unclear - are you trying to *create* this sort of response (which is pretty odd, btw - have you considered using a header for the hash instead?) or parse it?

Comment: Parse it, please. Maybe it will help me.

Comment: Okay, so what format do you have the response in at the moment? A single string? That should be easy enough to separate into a first line and "the rest", then parse "the rest" as an XML document (e.g. XDocument.Parse). What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have XML without hashcode.
My code in c#

 [WebMethod]
        public RESPONSE GET( string id)
        {
            RESPONSE res = new RESPONSE();
            res.ERR_TEXT = "";
            res.RE = "";            
            res.Stamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddthh-mm-ssz");
            res.PaymentID = id;
           
            return res;            
        }

Comment: So you're not trying to parse it - you're trying to create it. Please put a *lot* more effort into making it clear what you're trying to achieve, and do that in the *question* rather than in comments.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your first question. I'm trying to create this response.